# MySQL. Table modifications with subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I´m getting confused on this one and need some help.

I´ve got these tables:

1) PRODUCTOS (products)

```
+-------------+-----------------------------+---------------+------------------+
| PRODUCTO_NO | DESCRIPCION                 | PRECIO_ACTUAL | STOCK_DISPONIBLE |
+-------------+-----------------------------+---------------+------------------+
|          10 | MESA DESPACHO MOD. GAVIOTA  |        550.00 |               50 |
|          20 | SILLA DIRECTOR MOD. BUFALO  |        670.00 |               25 |
|          30 | ARMARIO NOGAL DOS PUERTAS   |        460.00 |               20 |
|          50 | ARCHIVADOR CEREZO           |       1050.00 |               20 |
|          60 | CAJA SEGURIDAD MOD B222     |        280.00 |               15 |
|          70 | DESTRUCTORA DE PAPEL A3     |        450.00 |               25 |
|          80 | MODULO ORDENADOR MOD. ERGOS |        550.00 |               25 |
+-------------+-----------------------------+---------------+------------------+
```

and:

2) PEDIDOS (orders)

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+
| PEDIDO_NO | PRODUCTO_NO | CLIENTE_NO | UNIDADES | FECHA_PEDIDO |
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+
|      1000 |          20 |        103 |        3 | 1999-10-06   |
|      1001 |          50 |        106 |        2 | 1999-10-06   |
|      1002 |          10 |        101 |        4 | 1999-10-07   |
|      1003 |          20 |        105 |        4 | 1999-10-16   |
|      1005 |          30 |        105 |        2 | 1999-10-20   |
|      1006 |          70 |        103 |        3 | 1999-11-03   |
|      1007 |          50 |        101 |        2 | 1999-11-06   |
|      1008 |          10 |        106 |        6 | 1999-11-16   |
|      1009 |          20 |        105 |        2 | 1999-11-26   |
|      1011 |          30 |        106 |        2 | 1999-12-15   |
|      1012 |          10 |        105 |        3 | 1999-12-06   |
|      1013 |          30 |        106 |        2 | 1999-12-06   |
|      1014 |          20 |        101 |        4 | 2000-01-07   |
|      1015 |          70 |        105 |        4 | 2000-01-16   |
|      1017 |          20 |        105 |        6 | 2000-01-20   |
+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+
```

Now, what I´ve got to do is to update column ´STOCK_DISPPONIBLE´(available stock) in table ´PRODUCTOS´ by subtracting from it total number of items being ordered for each item in stock. That means that for example I´ve got Table as product no 10, and I have to go through all the orders and see how many tables have been ordered and subtract that number from the total of the tables availables. What I came up with doesn´t work (well, I wouldn´t be here if it did work).

```
update PRODUCTOS set STOCK_DISPONIBLE= (STOCK_DISONIBLE - (select sum(p1.UNIDADES) from PEDIDOS p1 join PRODUCTOS p2 on p1.PRODUCTO_NO = p2.PRODUCTO_NO));
```

It could be that the logic is absolutely wonky here. But I get lost on this one and would very much appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you intend a simple correlated subquery:

```
update PRODUCTOS p
    set p.STOCK_DISPONIBLE = (p.STOCK_DISONIBLE -
                              (select sum(pe.UNIDADES)
                               from PEDIDOS pe 
                               where pe.PRODUCTO_NO = p.PRODUCTO_NO
                              )
                             );
```

The `join` in the subquery is unnecessary.

Comment: yes! thank you ever so much, I knew I am overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` to an aggregated version of table `PEDIDOS`:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTOS AS p1
JOIN (
   SELECT PRODUCTO_NO, SUM(UNIDADES) AS total_units
   FROM PEDIDOS 
   GROUP BY PRODUCTO_NO
) AS p2 ON p1.PRODUCTO_NO = p2.PRODUCTO_NO
SET p1.STOCK_DISPONIBLE = p1.STOCK_DISPONIBLE - p2.total_units
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b7ce2/1)